# ElasticSearch - query to append a string to an existing string in a document field

Tags: elasticsearch

All of our ElasticSearch documents contain a field called `Categories` which contains a string of comma-separated values.  The length of each value between the commas is 5 characters, and the field can be anywhere from 1 to 12 5-character values.

I need to run a query against the index which says append `,ABCDE` to the end of `Categories` field of all documents, **unless** the field already contains the value `ABCDE` in it, in which case do not append anything to the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use ElasticSearch [_update_by_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) like below**

```
POST my_index/my_type/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match": {
            "Categories": "ABCDE"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.Categories += ', ABCDE'",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

The above query will append string `', ABCDE'` to Categories if Categories doesn't contains the term `ABCDE`

Comment: Many thanks Ashraful.  Just to be sure I understand, the first part of the query syntax will look for Categories to contain 12345 anywhere in the string, and not just for where Categories = 12345?

Comment: @Stpete111 match query will look if the term `12345` contains in the Categories and since match is inside `must_not`, it will look for must not contains the term `12345` in Categories

Comment: Ashraful, just to verify the results, I have run just the search part of your query, but I changed `must_not` to `must` as I wanted to confirm that results which contain `ABCDE` are included in the results.  However, when I run it, it only brings back results where `Categories` equal `ABCDE` exactly. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Also, I noticed a mistake in my original post.  I had `12345` where I meant to have `ABCDE`, please see edited post.

Comment: @Stpete111 what is field type of `Categories` ? `text` or `keyword` ?

Comment: It is type `Text`

Comment: @Stpete111 text type uses standard tokenizer which provides grammar based tokenization (based on the Unicode Text Segmentation algorithm. i.e if categories contains text `The 2 QUICK Brown-Foxes jumped over the lazy dog's bone` it will be tokenized into `[The, 2, QUICK, Brown, Foxes, jumpe, d, over, the, lazy, dog's, bone]` So this catgories will be match if any of the tokens provided in the match query

Comment: Thank you Ashraful, l have found the problem.  I was only returning limited results in my query instead of the whole population, and those limited results were all with ABCDE only in the field.  I have marked your answer.  Thanks again.